# .htaccess rewrite rule for removing numerical id in the path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an over 10 yr old website with lots of external links.

The URL format is like `top-level/show/12345/text-name`.

I'm in the process of upgrading the system and the new system supports more user friendly URL with out the 12345 numerical id, like; `top-level/show/text-name`.

I'm planning on migrating existing contents preserving the text-name.

How do I specify in .htaccess to remove the `/12345` level in the path?
12345 can be any number, thousands.

Comment: can you post anything that you can that would help

Answer (score 0):

Change any old url on your site as far as they are not already automatically changed. Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and allowed to work (FollowSymLinks must be allowed). Then add the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^show/[0-9]+/([^/]+)/?$ show/$1 [R,L]
```

Change the `R` flag to `R=301` once you have tested that the redirect works as expected. Changing this will mark this as a permanent redirect. You also might want to remind any users that they should update their bookmarks.

Comment: Thanks @Sumurai8, this worked perfectly!                         ^show/([0-9]+)/(.+) /show/$2 [R=301] will be used at the end.

Comment: You should use the `L` flag as well (so you end up with `[R=301,L]`). Otherwise Apache will continue reading other rules, which might cause strange behaviour when you add rules in the future.